# What's the format of a CUID in SAP BI/BO?

Tags: regex, business-intelligence, business-objects, uid

I'm interfacing with an SAP BI/BO server and some webservices require an input id, called "CUID" (Cluser Unique ID). for example, there's a webservice getObjectById which requires a CUID as input.

I'm trying to make my code more robust by checking if the CUID entered by a user makes sense, but I can't find a regular expression that properly describes how a CUID looks like. There is a lot of documentation for GUID, but they're **not** the same. Below are some examples of CUID's found in our system and it looks like they are well-formatted but I'm not sure:

```
AQA9CNo0cXNLt6sZp5Uc5P0
AXiYjXk_6cFEo.esdGgGy_w
AZKmxuHgAgRJiducy2fqmv0
ASSn7jfNPCFDm12sv3muJwU
AUmKm2AjdPRMl.b8rf5ILww
AaratKz7EDFIgZEeI06o8Fc
ATjdf_MjcR9Anm6DgSJzxJ8
AaYbXdzZ.8FGh5Lr1R1TRVM
Afda1n_SWgxKkvU8wl3mEBw
AaZBfzy_S8FBvQKY4h9Pj64
AcfqoHIzrSFCnhDLMH854Qc
AZkMAQWkGkZDoDrKhKH9pDU
AaVI1zfn8gRJqFUHCa64cjg
```

My guess would: start with capital `A`, then add 22 random characters in range `[0-9A-Za-Z_.]`. but perhaps it could be the A means something else and after awhile it would be using `B`...

Is anyone familiar with this type of id's and how they are formatted?

(quick side question: do I need to escape the "dot" in the square brackets like this `\.` to get the actual dot character?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the different ID types and their purpose is described in the SAP KB note [1285103](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1285103): *What are the different types of IDs used in the BusinessObjects Enterprise repository?*

However, I couldn't find any description of the format of the CUID. I wouldn't make any assumptions about it though, other than the fact that it's alphanumeric.

I did a quick query on a repository and found CUIDs consisting up to 35 characters and beginning with the letters `A`,`B`,`C`,`F`,`k` and `M`.

If you look at the repository database, more specifically the table `CMS_INFOOBJECTS7`, you'll notice that the column `SI_CUID` is defined as a `VARCHAR2`, 56 bytes in size (Oracle RDBMS).

Thus, a valid regex expression to match these would be `[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+`.